# How to extract BrowserState from BrowserAction monad?

Tags: haskell

I'm coding a http client as a learning project with the use of network-http package (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.2) .

There is a Network.Browser module which defines getBrowserState function.

Probably just a lame beginner question but how can I get BrowserState record from BrowserAction monad if Network.Browser module does not export data constructor or record's lift function ?

```
import Network.Browser

-- getBrowserState :: BrowserAction t (BrowserState t)

extractBS :: BrowserAction t (BrowserState t) -> BrowserState t
-- ??? implementation ???
```

In addition what about further handling of BrowserState fields like bsCookies, bsDebug, bsProxy etc. ? (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.2.2/doc/html/src/Network-Browser.html#BrowserState)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. A `BrowserAction` describes an action, while a `BrowserState` describes the current state of the browser at some point within an action.

The only way of getting something out of a `BrowserAction` is to run it with the `browse` function.

```
browse :: BrowserAction conn a -> IO a
```

It's essentially the same as why you can't get a `Something` out of an `IO Something`, except here you have the function `browse` which allows you to "get stuff out of" a browser action by running it.

For example, you can make an action that extracts the current browser state after the original action and run that:

```
browse (action >> getBrowserState) :: IO (BrowserState conn)
```

Note the `IO` in the type here, as running the action may have side effects.

That said, I suspect that what you really want is to make the code that needs the current browser state part of an action.

```
browse $ do action
            state <- getBrowserState
            -- do stuff with the state
```

Note that `BrowserAction` has a `MonadIO` instance, so you can still do `IO` stuff by using `liftIO`.

```
browse $ do -- browsing
            liftIO $ putStrLn "foo"
            -- more browsing
```

In other words, you shouldn't think of it as getting stuff out of a `BrowserAction`. You should instead think of how to make the browsing-related code part of a `BrowserAction` which you then run with `browse`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did suspected getBrowserState returns some generally stored state instead of state within a current action. Btw. to get Something from IO Something can be done with <- expression, but I'm sure that is known to you.

Comment: @DavidUnric: Yes, do-notation lets you pretend that you've taken something out of a monad, but what you're actually doing is making composite actions out of simpler ones. You don't really get anything out until you run it.

Comment: @hammer> yes, if I think about it a while I feel stupid now to even think about a "global"/stored state in haskell :) Mentioned extraction of IO monad is no exception as clarified by you. It's just part of composed functions in one monad action.